# Lookup a slug across multiple models in django

Tags: python, django

Let say you have three models:

- users.py
- blogpost.py
- questions.py

How is it possible to have a url structure where all three - both users, blogposts and questions - are retrieved by their slug. E.g.:

(user lookup): www.site.com/Andrew

(blogpost lookup) www.site.com/howto-lookup-by-slug-in-django

(question lookup) www.site.com/how-do-you-look-up-by-slug-in-django

Comment: using class based or traditional (function) views? and will there ever be a circumstance where there are duplicates (a `question` slug is the same as a `blogpost` slug)?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [how Django looks up a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) for given url, you will find out that:

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.

So, there can only be url for `www.site.com/<slug>` and you have to do appropriate queries in your view. My guess would be to establish priorities - for instance first check blogs, then users then questions.

Completely different approach is possible at the model level. You can externalize `slug` attribute to a separate model and link to it from every other model that has a `slug`. This way you could establish uniquness of a `slug` accross all models and provide easier way to query by `slug`.